# Python nested dictionary and nested update

Tags: python

I would like to update or create a nested dictionary without altering the existing content.

In the example below I will try to add the couple `{'key2.2': 'value2.2'}` nested as a child to the entry key2.

- *Case 1:* the parent key (key2) exists :

```
    mydict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.1': 'value2.1'}}
    mydict['key2'].update({'key2.2': 'value2.2'})
    pprint(mydict)
```

> `{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.1': 'value2.1', 'key2.2': 'value2.2'}}`

This is what I expected, no problem here.

- *Case 2:* the parent key (key2) **does not exists** :*

```
    mydict = {'key1': 'value1'}
    mydict['key2'].update({'key2.2': 'value2.2'})
```

> `KeyError: 'key2'`

Seems logic, so let's try something else..

```
    mydict = {'key1': 'value1'}
    mydict.update({'key2': {'key2.2': 'value2.2'}})
    pprint(mydict)
```

> `{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.2': 'value2.2'}}`

Perfect ! 
Let's check if this works with case 1 too.

- *Case 1B:* the parent key (key2) exists :

```
    mydict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.1': 'value2.1'}}
    mydict.update({'key2': {'key2.2': 'value2.2'}})
    pprint(mydict)
```

> `{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.2': 'value2.2'}}`

The existing entry `{'key2.1': 'value2.1'}` got deleted, this is **not** what I want.

What would be the best way to achieve what I want ? Like a nested update ? 
I know this would be possible with a couple of try:/except KeyError:, but it doesn't seems very clean.

Comment: Isn't *case 1* already does what you want?

Comment: I don't know in advance if I will be in the *case 1* or *case 2* situation, so I need a way to achieve the expected outcome no matter the case !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(dict)
mydict.update({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.1': 'value2.1'}})
mydict['key2'].update({'key2.2': 'value2.2'})
print(mydict)

mydict = defaultdict(dict)
mydict.update({'key1': 'value1'})
mydict['key2'].update({'key2.2': 'value2.2'})
print(mydict)
```

Outputs:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.1': 'value2.1', 'key2.2': 'value2.2'}})
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.2': 'value2.2'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mydict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.1': 'value2.1'}}
if "key2" in mydict:
    mydict["key2"].update({'key2.2': 'value2.2'})
else:
    mydict["key2"] = {'key2.2': 'value2.2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
mydict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'key2.1': 'value2.1'}}
mydict['key2.2'.split('.')[0]].update({'key2.2' : 'value2.2'})
print(mydict)
```

Output:

```
{'key2': {'key2.2': 'value2.2', 'key2.1': 'value2.1'}, 'key1': 'value1'}
```